# Do Cookies\Sessions\Site Information from a non-selenium browser contaminate into a Selenium browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I like to access https://example.com with my normal non-selenium Firefox browser. Because I frequent this site regularly, my non-selenium Firefox browser has cookies, site & session information, and even browsing history. My selenium script has the the following, which goes to https://example.com

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://example.com')
```

Will information from my non-selenium Firefox browsing sessions, contaminate with the selenium Firefox instance executed by the script above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browser capable of using a user profile will start a new session by default using a blank profile, which would contain no cookies or history. There are options one can usually set to use an existing user profile, or at least a copy of one. The short answer is, “No, by default, your non-Selenium browsing information should not leak into your browser sessions started using Selenium.”

Note that in the interest of completeness, there are exceptions, notably Internet Explorer, and EdgeHTML-based Microsoft Edge, but those browsers don’t use user profiles as such.